# Handling overlapping button by touch ended event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

[image: not coming like this]I am confused with this logic, please help me find a solution.
I am making a `uibutton` with every touch on `UIview` and it works in principle. **But the button should not overlap with the previous button when touching a second time.**
Here is the code for creating a button on a 'touch ended' event.

```
int const kRadius = 4;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        loop = [[MagnifierView alloc] init];
        loop.viewToMagnify = self;
        [loop setNeedsDisplay];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [btnCamera removeFromSuperview];
    if(self.activateEditMode){
        self.touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(addLoop)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:NO];

        // just create one loop and re-use it.
        if(loop == nil){
            loop = [[MagnifierView alloc] init];
            loop.viewToMagnify = self;
        }

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        loop.touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];



        [loop setNeedsDisplay];
    }else{
        // Message
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self handleAction:touches];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.touchTimer invalidate];
    self.touchTimer = nil;
    if(self.activateEditMode){
        [self createCameraBtn];
        [loop removeFromSuperview];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(102/255) green:(102/255) blue:(102/255) alpha:1]];
    }
}
```

Whenever the user is touching the view I am taking the x,y value of the view and save them into a `CGPoint` `loop.touchPoint`
and I also save the x,y values into a database to check before creating the next button against the previous x,y values which I stored in the database.

So far everything is ok.
When I am handling the previous values, I am not doing it correctly in the code.

**Handling code and button creation**

```
- (BOOL)handleOverlapping{
    for (ImageInfo *img in self.profileInfo.imageInfo)
    {
       int xr = [img.xcord intValue] + kRadius;
       int yr = [img.ycord intValue] + kRadius;
       if ((([selectedXCord intValue] - kRadius) <= xr) && (([selectedYCord intValue] - kRadius) <=yr))
       {
       [CSNotificationView showInViewController:[(SkinViewController *)[self.superview nextResponder] navigationController]
                                        style:CSNotificationViewStyleError message:kOVERLAPING_REDDOT_ERROE];
           return false;
       }
      else if ((([selectedXCord intValue] - kRadius+10) <= xr) && (([selectedYCord intValue] - kRadius+10) <=yr))
        {
            [CSNotificationView showInViewController:[(SkinViewController *)[self.superview nextResponder] navigationController]
                                               style:CSNotificationViewStyleError message:kOVERLAPING_REDDOT_ERROE];
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**button creation**

```
- (void)createCameraBtn{
    //[self colorOfPoint:loop.touchPoint];
    selectedXCord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:loop.touchPoint.x-12];
    selectedYCord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:loop.touchPoint.y-75];

    // Check whether user focusing on monitored region.
    if(![self handleOverlapping])
        return;
//    else if (![self red:red green:green blue:blue])
//        return;

    btnCamera = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnCamera.frame = CGRectMake(loop.touchPoint.x-12, loop.touchPoint.y-75, 25, 25);
    [btnCamera setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCamera setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(captureSkin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addSubview:btnCamera];
}
```

I think I am wrongly handling the overlap method.

In this method 
 1. `xr,yr` are the x,y values of the previous button, 
 2. `selectedYcord,selectedXcore` is the current touch position.
 3. every button has width and height of 25

What I want to do here is to make sure that the second button does not overlap with previous one.

example x,top,y,bottom values.

It can create button minus 10 points with respect to the previous button for any side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think issue at loop.touchPoint.x that you did not get actuly touch x point that return same that's why you getting ovverrite button becouse its place at same x and y posstion.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally My code is corret,i did mistake in a for loop..its checking every single time because i returned a value so it never check another button.finally i came to solution by changing code like this..

```
- (BOOL)handleOverlapping{
    BOOL firstCondition=false;
    BOOL secondCondition=false;
    for (ImageInfo *img in self.profileInfo.imageInfo){

        int xr = [img.xcord intValue];
        int yr = [img.ycord intValue];

        if (xr+12<=[selectedXCord intValue]||xr-12>=[selectedXCord intValue]){
            firstCondition=true;
        }
       else if (yr+12<=[selectedYCord intValue]||yr-12>=[selectedYCord intValue]){
            secondCondition=true;
        }
       else
       {
           [CSNotificationView showInViewController:[(SkinViewController *)[self.superview nextResponder] navigationController]
                                              style:CSNotificationViewStyleError message:kOVERLAPING_REDDOT_ERROE];
           return false;

       }




    }
    if (firstCondition || secondCondition){
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```